# Htaccess redirect always keeps the old path

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, path, rule

I would like to make a redirect using htaccess rules to point ALL links from

> mywebsite.com/subfolder1/subfolder2/...whatever-path....

to

> mywebsite.com/subfolder1

But the problem is that whatever rule I use it always keeps the old path in the destination link, for example:

> mywebsite.com/subfolder1/subfolder2/mypage.php

becomes

> mywebsite.com/subfolder1/mypage.php

I tried all the following possibilities:

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://mywebsite.com/subfolder1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^subfolder1/subfolder2/(.*)$ /subfolder1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^/subfolder1/subfolder2/(.*)$ /subfolder1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

Redirect 301 /subfolder1/subfolder2 https://mywebsite.com/subfolder1

RedirectMatch 301 /subfolder1/subfolder2(.*)$ /subfolder1/$1

RedirectMatch 301 ^/subfolder1/subfolder2/?$ https://mywebsite.com/subfolder1
```

I have placed the "Options +FollowSymLinks" and "RewriteEngine on" rules before them, but NONE of them worked.

Can someone tell what's wrong and how to find the right rule?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteRule ^subfolder1/subfolder2/(.*)$ /subfolder1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

With `$1`you attach the content of `(.*)` to the redirected URL. Remove them from code and

http://mywebsite.com/subfolder1/subfolder2/whatever-path
will be
http://mywebsite.com/subfolder1

Comment: Thank you so much Heinz you saved my life! I didn't notice there was a wildcard in the destination link... Now it works great!!